# Calculate how many items within a range

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get some data together based on some data.

So for example as seen below the `items` array displays the total amount of times a number is between the range in the data, so for example `4500` - `5000` has got 4 numbers between that range.

However adding these up doesn't give an accurate representation of the amount of items there is. If this makes sense? As in the `result` the count for `7000` is 13, however this should be 8.

```
const data = [ 2200, 3900, 4500, 4500, 4800, 5000, 6000, 6000 ]

const items = [
    { value: { from: 2000, to: 2500 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 2500, to: 3000 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 3000, to: 3500 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 3500, to: 4000 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 4000, to: 4500 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 4500, to: 5000 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 5000, to: 5500 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 5500, to: 6000 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 6000, to: 6500 }, count: null },
    { value: { from: 6500, to: 7000 }, count: null },
].map(item => {
    item.count = data.filter(x => x <= item.value.to && x >= item.value.from).length;
    return item;
});

let counter = 0;
result = items.map(i => {
    counter += i.count;
    return { value: i.value.to, label: i.value.to, count: counter }
}).filter(Boolean);

console.log({items, result});
```

What I SHOULD have is the following, as this data is for an **UPTO** dropdown.

```
[
    { value: { from: 2000, to: 2500 }, count: 1 },
    { value: { from: 2500, to: 3000 }, count: 1 },
    { value: { from: 3000, to: 3500 }, count: 1 },
    { value: { from: 3500, to: 4000 }, count: 2 },
    { value: { from: 4000, to: 4500 }, count: 4 },
    { value: { from: 4500, to: 5000 }, count: 6 },
    { value: { from: 5000, to: 5500 }, count: 6 },
    { value: { from: 5500, to: 6000 }, count: 8 },
    { value: { from: 6000, to: 6500 }, count: 8 },
    { value: { from: 6500, to: 7000 }, count: 8 },
]
```

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: You are counting `4500` twice. Two times from `4000` to `4500` and then two times from `4500` to `5000`. Also I think there are other duplicated counts so you will have to do something with the equalities inside the filter.

Comment: Expected output : `{ from: 5000, to: 5500 }, count: 6` why count is 6? Are you sure your input data is correct?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained, this data is for a dropdown to select the upto price, so selecting 7000 everything below should be counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not consider both `from` and `to` inside the boundary. This will result in having common elements in individual groups.

**For example:** From 4000 to 4500 means numbers greater than 4000 and less than or equal to 4500.

Here in the above example, the lover boundary donot overlaps, so that the individual groups donot have common elements.

```js
const data = [2200, 3900, 4500, 4500, 4800, 5000, 6000, 6000]

const items = [
  { value: { from: 2000, to: 2500 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 2500, to: 3000 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 3000, to: 3500 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 3500, to: 4000 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 4000, to: 4500 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 4500, to: 5000 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 5000, to: 5500 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 5500, to: 6000 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 6000, to: 6500 }, count: null },
  { value: { from: 6500, to: 7000 }, count: null },
].map(item => {
  item.count = data.filter(x => x <= item.value.to && x > item.value.from).length;
  return item;
});
let counter = 0;
result = items.map(i => {
  counter += i.count;
  return { value: i.value.to, label: i.value.to, count: counter }
}).filter(Boolean);

console.log({ items, result });
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well, having issues with my from data from but this will be another silly error of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a single loop and map a new object with count.

```js
const
    data = [2200, 3900, 4500, 4500, 4800, 5000, 6000, 6000],
    values = [{ value: { from: 2000, to: 2500 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 2500, to: 3000 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 3000, to: 3500 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 3500, to: 4000 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 4000, to: 4500 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 4500, to: 5000 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 5000, to: 5500 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 5500, to: 6000 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 6000, to: 6500 }, count: null }, { value: { from: 6500, to: 7000 }, count: null }],
    items = values.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        count: data.reduce((s, x) => s + (x <= item.value.to), 0)
    }));

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```